# How to make query in mysql select the father and the children without repeating the father row

Tags: php, sql

I would like to obtain the table data and the data of the children are in another table but I do not know how to make the query.

what I know how to do is a normal query select * form table 1, I know how to perform "inner join" but I do not want the data in table 1 "parent" repeated

```
select * form parent INNER JOIN childs on parent.pnt_id=childs.id_pnt;
```

parent                              childs

```
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
| id  |   pnt_id | info |infotwo|   | id  |   id_pnt |n_child|...  
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
|    1|         5| home | big   |   |    5|         1|  joan | 
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
|    2|         3| work | fat   |   |    3|         1|  luci |  
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+  
|    3|         0| soft |  thin |   |    6|         2|  troy |  
+-----+----------+------+-------+   +-----+----------+-------+
```

I would like a query in the form of

```
$parents = arrar (
          info -> "home",
          infotwo -> "big",
          data_child -> arrar (
                      n_child -> "joan",
                      n_child -> "luci"
                     )
)
```

Comment: I've only seen functionality like the one you need in MyBatis so far. I guess that's out of your scope. At least you'll know it does exist in the wild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select p.info, p.infotwo, group_concat(n_child) as children
from parent p join
     childs c
     on p.pnt_id = c.id_pnt
where p.pnt_id = 1
group by p.info, p.infotwo;
```